# How does this object initialization work, for props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, initialization, constants

I found this code, and would like an explanation of why '={}' is needed after the initializations.
What I can figure out is 
1) const makes the 'props' object const (not it's contents)
2) fields such as 'elementDimensions.width' are initialized but the object is set to ={}, why is that needed?
3) at the end it's '= props', are 'props' possibly adding fields to this object?
Thanks.

```
export default (props) => {
    const {
        elementDimensions: {
            width = 0,
            height = 0
        } = {},
        isActive = false,
        isOutside = true,
        point: {
            x = 0,
            y = 0
        } = {}
    } = props;

    return (
        <div>
            {`x: ${x}`}<br />
....
```

Comment: `const` does not make the `props` object const. (Objects can’t be const at all, but the `props` variable isn’t const either.) Anyway, what you have there is [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variables_names_and_providing_default_values).

Answer (score 1):

1. This is *destructuring syntax*, not plain variable assignment. The variables extracted from `props` are the ones that are `const`s and cannot be reassigned - that is, the variables named `width`, `height`, `isActive`, `isOutside`, `x`, and `y`. (There is no object initialization here - `props` is already defined, as a parameter to the function)
2. The `= {}` is required to provide a default value for `elementDimensions`. Without it, the destructuring of `width` and `height` will fail if `props.elementDimensions` is undefined:

```js
const props = {};
const {
  elementDimensions: {
    width = 0,
    height = 0
  }
} = props;
```

3. The `= props` is just more destructuring syntax. For example

   ```
   const { foo } = bar;
   ```

extracts the `foo` property from the `bar` object, and puts it into a variable named `foo`.

Similarly to `= bar` above, the `= props` in your code extracts properties from the `props` object, and puts them into variable names.

Comment: Wow that's great! Thanks.  Since elementDimensions and point are named, are they  not part of 'props' argument (they are not destructured) but subfields are.  They are not required for destructuring in this case?

Comment: Whenever the left-hand side of a destructuring assignment contains `<prop>: { <somethingelse> }`, `prop` will not be extracted into a variable: rather, any variables extracted will depend on what's in `<somethingelse>`. What comes before a colon describes the property to look into for further extraction, but does not extract that standalone property itself.